# Non-conformable arrays in R

Tags: r

```
y <- matrix(c(7, 9, -5, 0, 2, 6), ncol = 1)
try <- t(y)
tryy <- try %*% y
i <- solve(tryy)
h <- y %*% i %*% try

uniroot(as.vector(solve(((1-x) * diag(6)) + h)), c(-Inf, Inf))

Error in (1 - x) * diag(6) : non-conformable arrays
```

The purpose of this command  `uniroot(as.vector(solve(((1-x) * diag(6)) + h)), c(-Inf, Inf))` is to solve the characteristics equation det[(1-λ)I+h] = 0

where, λ=eigenvalues , I=identity matrix , h=hat matrix=y(y'y)^(-1)y'

here  λ is unknown ,we have to solve for it.

I am not understanding where is the problem here? I have tried as:

```
  as.vector(solve(6*diag(6)+h))
```

This is not non-conformable. But why is not working inside the uniroot function?

Comment: Pleas check the length of `(1-x)` and compare to "length" of `6`.

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible, since `h` isn't defined.  My suspicion is that you should define `x` as a vector, not a matrix, and then the code should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, so I have to make a couple of assumptions. If you want the eigenvalues of `h`, then the characteristic equation is:

> det(h - I*λ) = 0

*not*

> det[(1-λ)I+h] = 0

So I used the former.

Given the above, the short answer is: do it this way.

```
f <- function(lambda) det(h -lambda*diag(6))
F <- Vectorize(f)                         
library(rootSolve)
uniroot.all(F,c(-1000,1000),n=2000)
# [1] 0 1

# or, much more simply
eigen(h)$values
# [1]  1.000000e+00  2.220446e-16  0.000000e+00 -2.731318e-18 -6.876381e-18 -7.365903e-17
```

So `h` has 2 eigenvalues, 0 and 1. Note that the built-in function `eigen(...)` finds 6 roots, but 5 of them are within the machine tolerance of 0.

The question about why your code fails is a bit more involved.

First, your code:

```
tryy <- try %*% y
```

is the dot product of y with itself (so, a scalar), returned as a matrix with one element. When you "invert" that using `solve(...)`

```
i <- solve(tryy)
```

you simply take the reciprocal, so `i` is also a matrix with 1 element. I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind.

Second, `uniroot(...)` does not work this way. The first argument must be a *function*; you've passed an expression which depends on `x`, which in turn is undefined. You could try:

```
f <- function(x) det(h-x*diag(6))
uniroot(f,c(-Inf,Inf))
```

but this wouldn't work either because (a) `uniroot(...)` works on a finite interval, (b) it requires that the function `f(...)` have different sign at the ends of the interval, and (c) in any event it would return only one root (the smaller one).

So you could use `uniroot.all(...)` in package `rootSolve`. `uniroot.all(...)` also requires a function as it's first argument, but there's a twist: the function must be "vectorized". This means that if you pass a vector of `lambda` values, `f(...)` should return a vector of the same length. Fortunately in R there is an easy way to "vectorize" a given function, as in:

```
F <- Vectorize(f).
```

Even this has it's limits. `uniroot.all(...)` also requires a finite interval, so we have to guess what that is, and also it evaluates F on n sub-intervals. So if your interval does not contain all the roots, or if the sub-intervals are not small enough, you will not find all the roots.

Using the built-in `eigen(...)` function is definitely the best option.